# Web-Bluetooth with Background Functionality?

Tags: google-chrome, web-bluetooth

Imagine the following scenario:

1. Customer places order for product on third-party website
2. Third-party website sends notification to server with details
3. Background process on android tablet waits for server push notification
4. Process pushes data to bluetooth device which then prints a label.

Is it feasible to have something running in the background on an android device that:

1. Maintains a stable connection that automatically reconnects to a bluetooth device
2. Accepts server push notifications and then sends commands to the bluetooth device
3. Is fairly fault tolerant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing, Web Bluetooth doesn't support background mode.

This isn't a near term goal according to https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/issues/422.